# Supplying section arguments for examples

Tags: coq

Consider this section:

```
Section MyMap.

Variables D R : Type.

Fixpoint mymap (f : D -> R) (l : list D) : list R :=
  match l with
  | nil => nil
  | d :: t => f d :: mymap f t
  end.

End MyMap.
```

Here I've used `Variables` to declare my domain and range types.  As a sanity check on the definition of my function, I would like to include an `Example`:

```
Example example_map_S : mymap S [0; 1; 2] = [1; 2; 3].
Proof.
  simpl; trivial.
Qed.
```

However it seems I can't do so within my section.  Instead I get:

```
Error: The term "S" has type "nat -> nat" while it is expected to have type "D -> R".
```

That's not too surprising, so let's try it another way:

```
Example example_map_S : @mymap nat nat S [0; 1; 2] = [1; 2; 3].
Proof.
  simpl; trivial.
Qed.
```

Which produces:

```
Error: The term "nat" has type "Set" while it is expected to have type "D -> R".
```

I suppose that's fair, section-ized `Variables` aren't the same thing as implicit arguments.  But it still leaves the question!

How can I supply concrete `Variables` to a term before closing the section, in order to create useful `Examples`?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. You have to close the section first to get the `Parameter`s to be lambda-lifted.

Comment: Boooooo.  It's obviously not a huge problem, but moving my examples far way from their definitions hurts their usefulness.

Comment: Btw, I think you want `Variables` instead of `Parameters`, because `Parameter` is another name for `Axiom`. One can see the difference after one closes the section and issues `Check mymap.` command.

Comment: In truth it is `Context {R S : Type}.` to make them implicit, but that needlessly complicates the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Section MyMap.
...
```

If we check the type of `mymap` *inside* the section, we get

```
Check mymap.
(* mymap : (D -> R) -> list D -> list R *)
```

Of course, we can't unify `D` and `R` with `nat`, since `D` and `R` are some locally postulated types.

However, we can sort of simulate your example in this generalized setting, showing the expected property of the `mymap` function:

```
Example example_nil (f : D -> R) :
  mymap f [] = [] := eq_refl.

Example example_3elems (f : D -> R) (d0 d1 d2 : D) :
  mymap f [d0; d1; d2] = [f d0; f d1; f d2] := eq_refl.

End MyMap.
```